# Replace whole values in a column with another column using condition

Tags: r, replace, match, rename

I have "reference data" that contain depth values and corresponding levels up to n number levels as follows;

```
depth   levels
0.06    1
0.19    2
0.33    3
0.48    4
0.63    5
0.8     6
```

I have another "data file" in csv as follows.

```
Date    Levels  variable
3-Jan   1       15.25
3-Feb   5       13.09
3-Mar   25      14.21
3-Apr   26      13.65
3-May   27      12.79
3-Jun   27      15.65
```

In this "data file" I have levels in 3rd column which is needed to change as per the "reference data". That means if level is 1 in the "data file" I need to replace that value '1' with its corresponding depth values from "reference data", i.e., 0.06. Like that, I want to change the whole values in the second column of my "data file".

So far I have tried `mapvalues` and `match`. But no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to merge the two datasets using the level. Then for each date you would have `variable` and `depth`, and you can do what you want with that (including overwriting the `level` with the `depth`, as you suggest).

```r
library(tidyverse)
reference_data <- read_table("depth   levels
0.06    1
0.19    2
0.33    3
0.48    4
0.63    5
0.8     6")

data_file <- read_table("Date    Levels  variable
3-Jan   1       15.25
3-Feb   5       13.09
3-Mar   25      14.21
3-Apr   26      13.65
3-May   27      12.79
3-Jun   27      15.65")

data_file %>% 
  left_join(reference_data, by = c("Levels" = "levels"))
#> # A tibble: 6 x 4
#>   Date  Levels variable depth
#>   <chr>  <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 3-Jan      1     15.2  0.06
#> 2 3-Feb      5     13.1  0.63
#> 3 3-Mar     25     14.2 NA   
#> 4 3-Apr     26     13.6 NA   
#> 5 3-May     27     12.8 NA   
#> 6 3-Jun     27     15.6 NA
```

<sup>Created on 2021-07-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>